# Apply CSS style by clicking on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a little photo album. My plan is if I click the little thumbnail image a border should appear and stay until I click another image. In other words: The hover should stay active when I clicked it.
Here is my Code:

```css
.images {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
.images img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
.images:hover,
.images:target {
  border: 4px solid #009EE0;
}
.table {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="images" id="image_first">
    <img src="http://budapesttimes.hu/wp-content/themes/newsroom14/img/placeholder.png" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://www.martinezcreativegroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/img-placeholder.png" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope you can help me!
Thanks in advance, jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:focus` and give `tabindex="1"` attribute.

```css
.images {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
.images img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
.images:hover,
.images:active,
.images:focus,
.images:target {
  border: 4px solid #009EE0;
}
.table {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="images" id="image_first" tabindex="1">
    <img src="http://budapesttimes.hu/wp-content/themes/newsroom14/img/placeholder.png" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </div>
  <div class="images" tabindex="1">
    <img src="http://www.martinezcreativegroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/img-placeholder.png" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Update:** Thanks to [Ivan Karaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5471481/ivan-karaman) for pointing this out. One thing I noticed is, you are using `.images` as a `<div>`. While this may perfectly work, it is always better to use `<a>` for generating the `#hash-values`, by giving them in a link. So, it would be better if you replace the below code:

```
<div class="images" id="image_first" tabindex="1">
```

With this:

```
<a class="images" id="image_first">
```

And also you don't need the "hack" `tabindex="1"` as well, as links always have the `:target`, `:focus`, and `:active` states by default. `:)`

Comment: @IvanKaraman For your kindest of information and **you commenting without checking**, see and learn with your own eyes, that **IT WORKS**: http://output.jsbin.com/yotojogiyi#image_first

Comment: @IvanKaraman What I gave you in the link is `:target` not `:focus`. Both work!

Comment: @IvanKaraman Mate, do you understand how `:target` not `:focus` work? Please!

Comment: @IvanKaraman From [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/on-target/): *The `:target` pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the URL and the id of an element are the same.* Do you understand now or you wanna create your own browser and argue senselessly?

Comment: watch my code below, if u don't understand how it works, in your answer url don't have hash because it does not work

Comment: @IvanKaraman I saw that you have changed your code by changing `div` to `a` right? And tell me one thing, why don't you provide an explanation in your code? Don't you consider that's so tiring to understand that?

Comment: remove .images:target and the result does not change

Comment: @IvanKaraman Did you see the URL? **The URL has a hash!!!** Mate, learn what `:target` does. Seriously.

Comment: @IvanKaraman Okay, lemme explain you in simple ways. When the `:target` rule is not there, the image doesn't start having the `active` or `hover`ed class applied without clicking, and having the hash (`id`) of the element in the URL. Do you understand what I said or do you need further demonstration?

Comment: @IvanKaraman After this I am giving up man. If you aren't interested in learning from experts, or at least respecting and understanding and learning others' views, you will never learn. All the best with your life and learning. `:)`

Comment: u don't understand me, when u click on .images URL don't getting hash and this selector is useless, if url has hash of image and u click on another image the result is wrong, better use only one way :target with hash in url or :focus

Comment: @IvanKaraman ^ I agree with you now. I can add a note to the OP that **this doesn't generate hash**. Thanks for telling this. I am gonna update my answer. Again, thank you!

Comment: @IvanKaraman Check my updated answer. Added a thanks to you too. Would you like to remove your downvote or do you want it to stay? `:P`

Answer (score 0):

active and focus might do the trick

```
.images:hover,
.images:focus,
.images:target
{
  border: 4px solid #009EE0;
}
```

It seems you can use :focus on div, but maybe not :active 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/

Comment: I don't think `<div>` can normally be focussed! They do not have a focus state.

Comment: I was assuming .images was a class on an anchor tag seeing as the :hover and :target were being applied @PraveenKumar

Comment: Yes, `div` can have `:hover` and `:target` classes but not `:active` and `:focus` classes.

Comment: You are missing the point dear @PraveenKumar it's not a div it's an anchor in the html <a class="images"

Comment: `.images` **is** a `<div>`. Check the question again? I see no `<a>` tags in the question.

Comment: All I see is: `<div class="images" id="image_first">`. Where did you see `<a class`?

Comment: oh, I was looking at someone's answer who thought the same as me, there you go. @PraveenKumar Well, I have never used hover and target on a div so I have learnt that today thanks to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you should use jQuery.
Try a little code of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img").click(function(){
      $(this).css({'border':'3px solid gren'});
   });

})
```

Comment: This is not tagged with jQuery! Also using your code, it is not possible to "unselect". Plus, jQuery and JavaScript are costlier than pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.images {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
.images img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
.images:hover,
.images:target {
  border: 4px solid #009EE0;
}
.table {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <a class="images" href="#image_first" id="image_first">
    <img src="http://budapesttimes.hu/wp-content/themes/newsroom14/img/placeholder.png" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </a>
  <a class="images" href="#image_second" id="image_second">
    <img src="http://www.martinezcreativegroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/img-placeholder.png" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You have technically changed the OP's HTML!

Comment: And you don't provide an explanation for what you have changed in from the OP's HTML. Just posting a code is bad, seriously bad!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!